# VK API Standalone app access_token

Tags: vkontakte-api, angular

Я разрабатываю небольшое веб приложение. В приложении я использую авторизацию ВК, для этого в ВК я создал приложение типа "Веб-сайт" и указал редирект на свой сервер, в котором собственно и получаю дату об юзере.
Мне понадобилось оставлять комментарий в ВК от имени авторизованного пользователя из своего приложения, и в vk api для этого есть метод `wall.createComment`, но этот метод работает только с ключом доступа пользователя, полученным в Standalone-приложении через Implicit Flow. И так я создал Standalone-приложении и попытался реализовать авторизации через него.

В Standalone-приложении после авторизации вк делает редирект на страницу `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html`
с токеном авторизации `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_toke=token`
Этот токен можно скопировать руками и использоывать, но UX такой себе.
Вопрос: как получить этот токен средствами js? Какова технология работы с Standalone-приложением.

На фронте я использую angular 15